# Every arrow from a terminal object to an initial object is an isomorphism

Tags: category-theory

I'm not sure my proof is correct for this exercise. If $t$ is terminal, $s$ is initial and $f : t \to s$ is an arrow, then by $s$ being initial we have a unique $g \colon s \to t$. Composition tells us that $gf = 1_t$, correct? How do we conclude $fg = 1_s$ and use the fact that $t$ is terminal?

Comment: I suggest thinking carefully about why $gf = 1_t$.  If you can say precisely why that must be true, then the dual argument should show that $gf = 1_s$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're exactly right! Write $0$ for the initial object, and $1$ for the terminal object. Moreover, say we have an arrow $f : 1 \to 0$. Then by composing with the (unique!) arrow $! : 0 \to 1$ we get

$$0 \overset{!}{\longrightarrow} 1 \overset{f}{\longrightarrow} 0$$

but since there is a unique arrow $0 \to 0$ (namely the identity), we see that $f \circ ! = \text{id}_0$.

Similarly, let's look at

$$
1 \overset{f}{\longrightarrow} 0 \overset{!}{\longrightarrow} 1
$$

since there is a unique arrow $1 \to 1$ (again, the identity), we see that $! \circ f = \text{id}_1$.

Then $!$ and $f$ are mutually inverse, and $0 \cong 1$.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Thank you. Can I ask where do we use the terminality of $1$? It seems like it's sufficient to know that $0$ is inital in order to get the unique arrow from $0 \to 1$.

Comment: Good observation! We actually don't use the full power of $1$ being terminal. All we use is that there's a _unique_ map from $1 \to 1$. In the case that $1$ is terminal, this follows from the universal property. But if $X$ is any object so that the only map $X \to X$ is the identity, we can run the same argument to see that any map $f : X \to 0$ must be an isomorphism.

Comment: It's a (fun?) exercise to run the same argument using explicitly the properties of $1$ instead of those of $0$ (or argue by duality). That is, if $Y$ is any object with only the identity arrow $Y \to Y$, then any arrow $f : 1 \to Y$ it must be an isomorphism.